# Hardware acceleration for video playing and streaming on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: video, driver, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, hardware-acceleration

I'm running Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi 2, but I'm not able to play video files using VLC and at the same time I can't stream HTLM5 videos using the web browser.
Now I'm trying to recompile VLC with hardware acceleration features and to use a different browser, but I need to use hardware acceleration for other software too such as Kaffeine or stuff like that.
Do you have any suggestion to enable the hardware acceleration by default on all the system?
Do I need to install any particular driver or change some configurations to use hardware acceleration for all the applications?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached the conclusion that is not possible to use the hardware acceleration for the whole system cause it's application dependent.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the following [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=59814&start=150) can be helpful

Comment: This is just for VLC. I have no problem to compile VLC with the right feature but I'm trying to address a different problem. I'd like to have hardware accelerated features on the whole system (not only using VLC).

Answer (score 0):

By default in Raspberry Pi The support for the hardware accelerated video playback is disabled. In order to use this feature you need to buy MPEG-2 and VC-1 license keys from the raspberry pi store. Since most of the videos are encoded using these two.

http://www.raspberrypi.com/mpeg-2-license-key/

Comment: Why do I need to buy these license keys? I'm able to play video perfectly using oxmplayer which uses the hardware acceleration so I don't understand why other software are unable to exploit hardware acceleration without any supplementary license keys.

Comment: I have the similar question, Even I bought the keys but still I did not find any improvements. I'm stuck at Qt mediaplayer.